# create a room in three.js based on the array with points

Tags: three.js

I am new in three.js. I create a room based on data from the array with points. I used the hints from [How to draw walls in ThreeJS from path or 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436056/how-to-draw-walls-in-threejs-from-path-or-2d-array/35451415#35451415) and my room is being created.
But:
1) you can not see all the walls - I know they are, because you can see this when using OrbitControls - but I do not want to see that
2) I want the walls to disappear as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/he6t10r8/ (when I make a 'traditional' room - only four walls - this solution works there, I can not pin it in such a place that it would work

Here is my code (  https://codepen.io/jagodanat/pen/pYqMMR?editors=1010):

```
var wallPoint = [
  {
    "X": 0,
    "Y": 0
  },
  {
    "X": 5,
    "Y": 0
  },
  {
    "X": 5,
    "Y": 3
  },
  {
    "X": 7,
    "Y": 3
  },
  {
    "X": 7,
    "Y": 5
  },
  {
    "X": 5,
    "Y": 5
  },
  {
    "X": 5,
    "Y": 7
  },
  {
    "X": 0,
    "Y": 7
  }
];

function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    container.id = 'container';
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 0.95*window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x889988 );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight);
    camera.position.set (10, 3, 15) ;
    scene.add(camera);
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, mesh );
    controls.enableZoom = false;
    controls.enablePan = false;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

     scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 ) );

    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );

 var walls = new THREE.Geometry();
    for(var i = 0; i < wallPoint.length; i++){
        var coordinates = wallPoint[i];
        walls.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, 0)); //vertex at floor level
        walls.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, 2.5)); //vertex at the top part of the wall, directly above the last
    }
    var previousVertexIndex = walls.vertices.length - 2;
    for( i = 0; i < walls.vertices.length; i += 2){
        walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i, i + 1, previousVertexIndex));
        walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i + 1, previousVertexIndex + 1, previousVertexIndex));
        previousVertexIndex = i;
    }
    walls.computeVertexNormals();
    walls.computeFaceNormals();

  var wallsMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        color: 0xff0ff
    } );
    console.log(walls);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(walls, wallsMaterial);
    mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI/3, 0.3, -0.3 );
    scene.add(mesh);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

All looks great, except that normals are calculated wrong. Try following:

1. Flip normals so that walls "look inside the room",
2. Don't do `walls.computeVertexNormals()` to avoid smoothing on corners.

**Suggested edit**: *(follow my comments in code)*

```js
var previousVertexIndex = walls.vertices.length - 2;
for (i = 0; i < walls.vertices.length; i += 2) {

    // fix#1 - swap 0 and 1 verts in each face to flip normals

    walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i + 1, i, previousVertexIndex));
    walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(previousVertexIndex + 1, i + 1, previousVertexIndex));
    previousVertexIndex = i;
}

//walls.computeVertexNormals(); // fix #2 - don't do this to make room corners sharp
walls.computeFaceNormals();

var wallsMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0ff,
    // side: THREE.DoubleSide // fix #3 - can do this to make room walls visible from both sides.
});
```

Additionally:
If you think of "merging" rooms into one plan, and giving walls some "thickness", consider using https://github.com/junmer/clipper-lib

Comment: thank you for quick response and for help - especially for comments explaining why I have to change something / give up something.
now everything looks ok.